# In which table is Activity assignee contact information stored in mysql?

Tags: activities

I'm looking for the table in which Activity assignee contact information is stored in mysql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most cases you would not use direct sql queries to look up or manipulate CiviCRM data.

Activity contacts, like most CiviCRM data, has an api which you can use to read, write, update and delete contacts in an activity.

You can browser this api on your own site using the Api Explorer:

[image: API Explorer]

Answer (score 5):

Depends on your version. From CiviCRM 4.4 the activity assignee can be found in the table civicrm_activity_contact, where record_type_id = 1 is 1 for source contact, 2 for assignee contact and 3 for target contact.

Comment: Thanks. How can I find the connection between civicm_contact table and record_type_id ? I don't seem to find the link..

Comment: @Tapash the civicrm_activity_contact table also has a contact_id field, use that? But I totally agree with Coleman that you should use the CiviCRM API to get to the activity contacts rather than poking directly in the tables.